# Sencha Touch Chart: Applying more than two gradients to bar

Tags: extjs, sencha-charts

Am very new to sencha touch as my requirement is to get the bar with four color gradients. but as of now am possible to apply only two color gradients for the bar .

following is my code,

```
gradients:
    [ {
        'id': 'v-1',
        'angle': 0,
        stops: {
            0: {
                color: '#79bbff'
            },

            100: {
                color: '#0d55a9'
            }
        }
    }]

series:
    [ {
        type: 'bar',
        renderer: function(sprite, storeItem, barAttr, i, store11) {

            barAttr.fill = colors[i % colors.length];
            return barAttr;
        }
    }]
```

Is it possible to apply more than two gradients for the single bar.Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance,
Naga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bug in the current release of sencha touch .... have posted a patch here

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?162233-Bug-Fix-Charts-1.-Could-not-apply-gt-2-stops-to-gradient-and-angle-not-respected&p=692723#post692723

Comment: Thanks a lot welshcathy, It's working fine nw.

Thanks, 
Naga